# How to add Finder and file,edit,Go,view,windows,help thing and a search for apps thing like mac OS on top of the Ubuntu 17.10 ( Gnome ) panel

Tags: gnome, files, themes, mac

Is there any way I can get the finder and file, edit, go, view, windows, help and app search thing that mac os has on top of the panel?

[image]